# kubectl - User "system:node:anth-admin-host1" cannot list resource "events"

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

I cannot apply this ClusterRole to my admin cluster to add rbac.authorization, I have used the same yaml file without problem for my user cluster.

How I solve the problem ?

Could be a problem of my kubeconfig file ?

```
ubuntu@anth-mgt-wksadmin:~$ cat cloud-console-reader.yaml
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
name: cloud-console-reader
rules:
apiGroups: [""]
resources: ["nodes", "persistentvolumes"]
verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
apiGroups: ["storage.k8s.io"]
resources: ["storageclasses"]
verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]

ubuntu@anth-mgt-wksadmin:~$ kubectl apply -f cloud-console-reader.yaml --kubeconfig kubeconfig
Error from server (Forbidden): error when retrieving current configuration of:
Resource: "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1, Resource=clusterroles", GroupVersionKind:    rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1, Kind=ClusterRole" Name: "cloud-console-reader", Namespace: ""
from server for: "cloud-console-reader.yaml": clusterroles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "cloud-console-reader" is forbidden: User "system:node:anth-admin-host1" cannot get resource "clusterroles" in API group "rbac.authorization.k8s.io" at the cluster scope


ubuntu@anth-mgt-wksadmin:~$ kubectl get nodes --kubeconfig kubeconfig
NAME STATUS ROLES AGE VERSION
anth-admin-host1 Ready control-plane,master 7d4h v1.20.5-gke.1301
anth-admin-host3 Ready 3h50m v1.20.5-gke.1301
anth-admin-host4 Ready 6d7h v1.20.5-gke.1301
anth-admin-host5 Ready 3h48m v1.20.5-gke.1301

ubuntu@anth-mgt-wksadmin:~$ kubectl cluster-info dump --kubeconfig kubeconfig |tail -1
Error from server (Forbidden): events is forbidden: User "system:node:anth-admin-host1" cannot list resource "events" in API group "" in the namespace "kube-system"
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem.

I have copied the admin.conf file from one admin cluster node to the admin workstation and renamed to kubeconfig

root@anth-admin-host1:~# cat  /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
apiVersion: v1
clusters:

all ok now!

Answer (score 0):

I tried reformatting your YAML file in my environment and noticed that some indentation changes can resolve your errors:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
Metadata:
 name: cloud-console-reader
rules:
-  apiGroups: [""] 
   resources: ["nodes", "persistentvolumes"]
   verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"] 
   apiGroups: ["storage.k8s.io"] 
   resources: ["storageclasses"] 
   verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
```

Points to be noted:

1. Clusterrole can also be created in [one liner using kubectl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#kubectl-create-clusterrole):

   ```
   kubectl create clusterrole pod-reader --verb=get,list,watch --resource=pods
   ```
2. Make sure that [RBAC should be enabled.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#kubectl-create-clusterrole)
3. If RBAC is enabled and the deployment-controller is missing a service account defined in the deployment-controller pod(s). You should be able to easily mitigate this issue by adding this SA and its Roles/Bindings.Two ways to do it,
   You can create the binding with [simple one liner](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#kubectl-create-clusterrolebinding) or [YAML](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#clusterrolebinding-example) way:

   To grant the permissions as "cluster-admin" ClusterRole to a user named "root".

   ```
   kubectl create clusterrolebinding root-cluster-admin-binding --clusterrole=cluster-admin --user=root
   ```
4. [kubeconfig](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/) file can be either from a trusted resource or specially-crafted. Here are some steps to [craft a kubeconfig file](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/). There can also be a possibility of [merging of kubeconfig files](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/#merging-kubeconfig-files).

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand how to solve the error:

User "system:node:anth-admin-host1" cannot list resource "events" in API group

Comment: You probably need to bind the dashboard service account to the cluster admin role
Otherwise, the dashboard services account doesn't have access to the data that would populate the dashboard.[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59605085/pods-is-forbidden-user-systemserviceaccountkubernetes-dashboardadmin-user)